# Making a gateway with virtual machines

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have 2 VMS.

I want the VM#1 to be the gateway of the VM#2.

VM#1 have 2 networks (eth0 - 10.0.2.15 (nat) & eth1 - 192.168.1.1 (internal network)).

VM#2 have 1 network (eth0 - 192.168.1.2 (internal network).

VM#1 can ping google.com because of the nat network. But what if I want VM#2 to be able to ping google too?

I'm just begining in that and I'd like to learn how to do it.

Here's what I already done:

VM#1

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

VM#2

```
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1
```

Now VM#2 can ping 10.0.2.15, but when I ping google.com I got an unknown host. So I tried 8.8.8.8 and then it's a 100% packet loss.

Any help ? :/

Comment: It is not obvious (at least to me) what is wrong. Is that your entire iptables rule set for VM#1? If not please post the entire rule set, Otherwise start to use tcpdump to observe if the packets get to VM#1 eth1 and then go out of eth0 and come back to eth0 ... (i.e. try to narrow down the problem area.)

Comment: @DougSmythies : here's `iptables --list-rules` => `-P INPUT ACCEPT` `-P FORWARD ACCEPT` `-P OUTPUT ACCEPT`

Comment: Well that doesn't have your FORWARD rules, and so does not agree with your question. (?) With a default policy of ACCEPT, you don't need them anyway. Please also show your nat rules. Please post the output from `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L`

Comment: Here's a pastebin as it's a lot of things..
http://pastebin.com/TCtN3B8H

Comment: ??? You do not have the iptables rules that you show in your question, so no it will not work.

Comment: My bad! Here's the correct one: http://pastebin.com/YzddiLCJ

Comment: It is not clear to me how or why the fragmented packet option is set, or even if it matters.

Comment: Start again, and double check your iptables rules as you add them, making sure NOT to specify the -f option.